# Remove Ship To label from Paypal Payment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal

How to remove Ship to label from PayPal payment. I am using Nuget package PayPal using MVC 4 site. The problem is everything works fine but i have to remove Ship To box. Is there any option to remove this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Payments Standard or Express Checkout?  I'm going to assume it's Express Checkout.

With that assumption being true, you can add NOSHIPPING=1 to your request in order to eliminate the shipping selection during checkout.

Comment: I am using Express Checkout using asp.net MVC nuget Paypal SDK. I tried to pass the param in url but not working. I also didn't found property.

Comment: It wouldn't go in the URL.  It would go in your SetExpressCheckout request.

Comment: I am using this method https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/ let me know how to hide shipping address.

Comment: where is the property? didn't found

Answer (score 0):

This link will solve my issue.

Thank for above suggestions.

[paypal api: take immediate payment without a shipping address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951320/paypal-api-take-immediate-payment-without-a-shipping-address)

Answer (score 0):

When I was using smart payment buttons, the following helped me to hide ship to.

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    var payableAmount = 3;
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                value: payableAmount
            }
        }],
        application_context: {
            shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: how can i do this in php? i am using php sdk.